# save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'log'

Tags: django, django-models

I am new to django.. I cannot understand what is this error. Can someone help me solve this issue?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Error logger\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Error logger\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Error logger\errorLogger\log\views.py", line 130, in add_solution
    s.save()
  File "C:\Error logger\errorLogger\log\models.py", line 41, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Error logger\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 682, in save
    self._prepare_related_fields_for_save(operation_name='save')
  File "C:\Error logger\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 932, in _prepare_related_fields_for_save
    raise ValueError(

Exception Type: ValueError at /add-solution/4/my-name-is-anirudh
Exception Value: save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'log'.
```

Also can someone explain what does the below do? I found that this is  needed for slug urls.. But  I don't understand what is super().save()

```
 def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug = self.slug or slugify(self.solution)
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Also what is the error that I am getting?

models.py

```
class Solutions(models.Model):
    log = models.ForeignKey(
        Log, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    solution = models.TextField(null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='images', blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = self.slug or slugify(self.solution)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ("Solution")
        verbose_name_plural = ("Solutions")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"  {self.solution} "
```

views.py

```
def add_solution(request, id, solution):
    log = Log()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SolutionForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            sol = form.cleaned_data['solution']
            image = request.FILES.get('image')
            s = Solutions()
            s.solution = sol
            s.image = image
            s.log = log
            s.save()

            message = messages.add_message(request, 25,
                                           'Solution added successfully')

            return HttpResponseRedirect(f'/solution/{id}/{solution}')

    else:
        form = SolutionForm()
        message = ''

    try:
        solution = Solutions.objects.filter(id=id).first()
        print(solution)

    except Solutions.DoesNotExist:
        solution = ''

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'message': message,
        'solution': solution
    }
    return render(request, 'add_solution.html', context=context)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the log first, so add

```
s.log.save()
```

Before

```
s.save()
```